# Write some query in MySQL DB

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

i wrote some query in LINQ to Entities.

```
var qq = from ss in oe.orders_to_providers_to_order
                     where
                     ss.status == "40" // status 'active'
                     && oe.orders_to_providers_to_order.Where(
                        x => 
                            (x.orders_id == ss.orders_id) && // the same order
                            (x.id != ss.id) && // not actual row
                            (x.status != "40" && x.status != "99") // not 'cancelled' and 'confirmed'
                        ).Count() == 0 // not exists
                     && 
                     oe.orders_to_providers_to_order.Where(
                        nnn => (nnn.orders_id == ss.orders_id) && // the same order
                            (nnn.id != ss.id)  &&  // not actual row
                            (nnn.status != "99") // not cancelled
                            ).Count() > 0 // must exists min. two rows in order
                     &&
                     oe.orders_to_providers_to_order.Where(
                        x => (x.orders_id == ss.orders_id) && // the same order
                             (x.status != "99") // not cancelled
                            ).Select(x => (x.orders_items.weight * x.quantity)).Distinct().Sum() <= WEIGHT_BORDER // weight limit
                     &&
                     oe.orders_to_providers_to_order.Where(
                        xn => (xn.orders_id == ss.orders_id) && // the same order
                             (xn.status != "99") // not cancelled
                            ).Select(xn => xn.orders_id).Distinct().Count() <= ORDER_QUANTITY_BORDER // order quantity limit
                     select new { ss.orders_items_id };
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT
1 AS `C1`, 
`Project6`.`orders_items_id`
FROM (SELECT
`Project4`.`orders_items_id`, 
`Project4`.`status`, 
`Project4`.`C1`, 
`Project4`.`C2`, 
`Project4`.`C3`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
`Extent6`.`orders_id`
FROM `orders_to_providers_to_order` AS `Extent6`
 WHERE (`Extent6`.`orders_id` = `Project4`.`orders_id`) AND (@gp5 != `Extent6`.`status`)) AS `Distinct2`) AS `C4`
FROM (SELECT
`Project2`.`orders_items_id`, 
`Project2`.`orders_id`, 
`Project2`.`status`, 
`Project2`.`C1`, 
`Project2`.`C2`, 
(SELECT
SUM(`Distinct1`.`C1`) AS `A1`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
`Extent5`.`weight` * (`Extent4`.`quantity`) AS `C1`
FROM `orders_to_providers_to_order` AS `Extent4` INNER JOIN `orders_items` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent4`.`orders_items_id` = `Extent5`.`id`
 WHERE (`Extent4`.`orders_id` = `Project2`.`orders_id`) AND (@gp4 != `Extent4`.`status`)) AS `Distinct1`) AS `C3`
FROM (SELECT
`Project1`.`orders_items_id`, 
`Project1`.`orders_id`, 
`Project1`.`status`, 
`Project1`.`C1`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `orders_to_providers_to_order` AS `Extent3`
 WHERE ((`Extent3`.`orders_id` = `Project1`.`orders_id`) AND (`Extent3`.`id` != `Project1`.`id`)) AND (@gp3 != `Extent3`.`status`)) AS `C2`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`orders_items_id`, 
`Extent1`.`orders_id`, 
`Extent1`.`status`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `orders_to_providers_to_order` AS `Extent2`
 WHERE ((`Extent2`.`orders_id` = `Extent1`.`orders_id`) AND (`Extent2`.`id` != `Extent1`.`id`)) AND ((@gp1 != `Extent2`.`status`) AND (@gp2 != `Extent2`.`status`))) AS `C1`
FROM `orders_to_providers_to_order` AS `Extent1`) AS `Project1`) AS `Project2`) AS `Project4`) AS `Project6`
 WHERE ((((@gp6 = `Project6`.`status`) AND (0 = `Project6`.`C1`)) AND (`Project6`.`C2` > 0)) AND (`Project6`.`C3` <= 10)) AND (`Project6`.`C4` <= 15)
```

In result of this query:

```
Unknown column 'Project2.orders_id' in 'where clause'
```

Table "orders_to_providers_to_order" contains a column "orders_id"

I use MySQL DB with .NET connector EF6

**After remove Distinct() from both subqueries there is no error and query is working.**

Why LINQ to Entities generated this query ? 
What is wrong in code ?

Comment: Better You update the model from database and try again

Comment: No changes, error the same after update model.